# ListPopupWindow doesn't display correctly in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-design-library

I'm trying to add a custom `ListPopupWindow` to a `TextView` wrapped in a `TextInputLayout`. The `TextView` has an OnClick listener that creates and shows the `ListPopupWindow`. Effectively I'm working on a custom Spinner.

If I change the `TextInputLayout` to a `LinearLayout` the `ListPopupWindow` displays correctly. Otherwise, the visual error is extra padding at the bottom of the popup.

XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <com.project.CustomTextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

CustomTextView:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Item 1");
    list.add("Item 2");

    ListPopupWindow popup = new ListPopupWindow(getContext());

    popup.setAnchorView(this);
    popup.setHeight(ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT);

    popup.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list));
    popup.show();
}
```

Result:

(This is just my non-generic implementation I'm working on. Notice the clipped bottom of the list. There is a ~30dp padding there that can't be removed).
[image: Notice the clipped bottom]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to solve this issue: It is definitely an issue with TextInputLayout being the anchor view for the popup. Here is how I got around it for now. Basically, add a LinearLayout to the TextInputLayout and use *its* parent for the context.

```
    LinearLayout menuAnchor = new LinearLayout(((ViewGroup) getParent()).getContext());
    addView(menuAnchor, 0);

    popup = new ListPopupWindow(menuAnchor.getContext());
    popup.setAnchorView(menuAnchor);
```